# How to export data from ms-access or excel to IBM DB2 I-Series database?

Tags: excel, ms-access, db2, export, ibm-midrange

I have some data in access(and excel) and I don't find a Free and not-really-hard-way to do it... any help?

I have excel and access 2003*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the DB2 iSeries database as an ODBC datasource in Windows. You should be able to do this with the Client Configuration Assistant that comes with the DB2 Client for Windows.

Open up your data in MS Access, you should be able to export it to an ODBC datasource from there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to export the data to a CSV file, then use the "Data Transfer to iSeries" utility that comes with Client Access.